# Normalize data server side on Laravel API like paularmstrong/normalizr

Tags: php, laravel, normalization

I am trying to mimic [paularmstrong/normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)'s functionality on my Laravel API.

The code below is just my idea, untested and probably filled with errors.

I am wondering if anybody knows a better way of doing this or if someone has written a handy package that already does it?

## Controller function

```
public function list(Request $request) {
  $items = Item::where(['id' => $id])
        ->with(['sets', 'things'])
        ->take(2);

  $data = [
    'entities' => [
        'items' => $this->toNormalizedResponse($items, ItemResource),
        'sets' => $this->toNormalizedResponse($items, SetResource),
        'things' => $this->toNormalizedResponse($items, ThingResource),
      ],
    'result' => $items->pluck('id')
    ];
  return response()->json($data, $this->getStatusCode(), $headers);   
}
```

## Trait to normalized data

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

trait NormalizeResponse
{
    /**
     * Normalize the data
     * @param $collection
     * @param string $jsonResponse Custom JsonResponse
     * @param string $id
     * @return array
     */
    function toNormalizedResponse($collection, $jsonResponse = JsonResponse::class, $id = 'id')
    {
        $collection = $this->getCollection($collection);
        if (is_null($collection)) {
            return [];
        }
        $data = [];

        foreach($collection as $model) {
            $data[$model->$id] = new $jsonResponse($model);
        }

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Convert to collection or return null if not an eloquent model
     * @param $collection
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection|null
     */
    private function getCollection($collection) {
        if ($collection instanceof Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection) {
            return $collection;
        }
        if ($collection instanceOf \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model) {
            return collect([$collection]);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

## ItemResource code

```
<?php

namespace App\Resources;

class ItemResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $data = [
            'id'     => (int) $this->id,
            'name'   => $this->name,
            'sets' => (isset ($this->sets)) ? $this->sets->pluck('id') : [],
            'things' => (isset ($this->things)) ? $this->things->pluck('id') : [],
        ];
        return $data;
    }
}
```

## Desired Json Structure

```
{
  entities: {
    sets: {
      23: {
        id: 23,
        name: 'Set 23'
      },
      42: {
        id: 42,
        name: 'Set 42'
      }
    },
    things: {
      21: {
        id: 21,
        name: 'Thing 21'
      },
      33: {
        id: 33,
        name: 'Thing 33'
      }
    },
    items: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Item 1',
        sets: [23],
        things: [33]
      },
      2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Item 2',
        sets: [23,42],
        things: [21]
      }
    }
  },
  result: [1, 2]
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/stidges/laravel-db-normalizer or https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-normalizer/blob/master/.php_cs

Comment: Hi, thanks for the links but I did run across these. The first is 6 years old and not compatible. The second is geared more for saving.

Answer (score 1):

I've long been searching for a similar solution and did not find one. Here is my take on it:

[Normalizr Laravel Eloquent API Resources](https://github.com/eightyfive/laravel-normalizr)